# C++ ignore or substr?

Tags: c++

Having the following input:

```
10/10/2013 04:59:37 PM,7.21,6000,9050.00,LT XT

10/10/2013 10:04:14 AM,9.88,246,99946.56,
```

I have used the `getline` fuction to read the whole line
using

```
substr(0,2); // i am able to read 10,2013, 04
```

I am unable to do `substr` from ',' onwards. I know using ignore function will work, is there a way to read the elements after the ',' individually?

Comment: substr(0,2) will only give you "10"... It might be easier to use one of Boost's tokenizer functions to tokenize on spaces and commas.

Comment: Why don't you increase the **Index** to start from the desired character? Read more about substr [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/).

Comment: @BongaMbombi, i can use that, but in the next few lines, the elements vary in size.

Comment: Have you tried getting the Length (**str.length()**) of the String first so to prevent index being outside bounds?

Comment: @BongaMbombi I think i should rephrase my question, my apologies.      My intention is to read each element individually so that I can parse them into int or double using atoi and atof. I managed to read to time. thereafter as the doubles and integer varies in size, I would not be able to use substr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find()` and `substr()` to separate a string by commas.

```
std::string line = "10/10/2013 10:04:14 AM,9.88,246,99946.56,";
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
size_t pos = 0;
size_t comma = line.find(",", pos);

while (comma != std::string::npos)
{
    tokens.push_back(line.substr(pos, comma - pos));
    pos = comma + 1;
    comma = line.find(",", pos);
}
// if there is anything left in the string after the last , add it to the vector
if (pos < line.size())
    tokens.push_back(line.substr(pos));
```